# Is it common to call our mother with ma'am in the western U.S?

Tags: hypocorisms

Is it common to call our mother with ma'am in the western U.S.? Does it show how close our relationship is with our mother?

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some examples of what you mean. Saying yes ma'am is not like saying yes Mom.

Comment: @tchrist It isn't, but it is. I have heard "ma'am" in an otherwise informal context to indicate a sense of affection, specifically from an adult child indicating something along the lines of "I don't take orders from anyone but Mom;"  or, perhaps, "I will accept your orders *this time* because of our relationship or situation" with the inflection making a great deal of difference as to the meaning.

Comment: Don’t Americans also sometimes call their teachers “ma’am”? I had an American friend once and I mistakenly thought they were referring to their teacher as “mom”, (mam) or whatever. Which puzzled me because in the UK we call teachers by their honorific Mr/Miss/Mrs ___ or just Sir/Miss etc. I have never heard another student call them mom (ma’am). Sounds too weird that even though I’m aware Americans do use this term, it does not automatically register to me as “ma’am” as in any woman, but mom — it is just that bizarre here. Unless of course it’s their actual mom or they’re talking to the Queen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never heard of anyone in Western US call their actual mother, ma'am. Though you may be confusing this for another word  `mam`. A northern British English word to mean one's mother. Or short hand for `mammy` (southern US).

[OED](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/mam) says this entry for MAM:

> ## NOUN
>
> 1. [British informal, dialect] One's mother.
>
> *‘my **mam** would have had a fit if I'd gone out dressed like that’*
>
> 2. [US informal] A term of respectful or polite address used for *any woman*.
>
> *‘‘You all ride them horses down here?’, ‘**Yes, mam.**’’*
>
> <sub>**Origin**</sub>
>
> Mid 16th century (in mam (**sense 1**)): perhaps imitative of a child's first syllables (see mama); mam (**sense 2**) is a variant of ma'am.

What strikes me is that `mam` and `ma'am` are practically phonetically identical in American English (Source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ma'am) pronounces 'ma'am' as [ˈmam  , after "yes" often əm]).

OED describe this variant of ma'am in sense 2 of the origin.

---

Dialectblog also says in [Mom, Mum, Mam: *Different words*?](http://dialectblog.com/2011/04/07/mom-mum-mam/):

> We have several informal words for “mother” in English: mum (heard in much of England), mom (heard in much of America), and mam (heard in Ireland and Northern England). But are these actually different words, or are they just, in some sense, the same word?
>
> **Although “mum,” “mam,” and “mom” read differently, they’re often pronounced in a very similar way. Here’s a comparison of three different dialects, and their “mom” pronunciations (don’t worry if you aren’t proficient in IPA — I’ll explain after)**:
>
> London: “mum” — [mɐm] 
>   General American: “mom” — [mɑm] 
>   Manchester, UK: “mam” — [mam] 
>   
>   Whether you understand the IPA symbols above or not, the point is that in these three dialects, the words are quite close in pronunciation.
>
> ---

## MAM may not be referring to Ma'am

Archaically, mam may have been the short-handed form of mammy:

> INFORMAL 
>  a child's word for their mother. 
>   *"he was screaming for his mammy"*
>
> OFFENSIVE 
>  (formerly in the southern United States) 
>  *a black nursemaid or nanny in charge of white children.* (...)

> (...) A mammy, also spelled mammie, is a U.S. stereotype, especially in the South, for a black woman who worked in a white family and nursed the family's children. The mammy figure is rooted in the history of slavery in the United States.

[A Dictionary of Archaic and Provincial Words, Obsolete Phrases ..., Volume 2](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=N25JAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA539&lpg=PA539&dq=mam+archaic&source=bl&ots=S9PmN1-Sh4&sig=ACfU3U3CGpQysiPOaPXgsCNXxZEaTY3SVw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0nK7l_PnjAhWnVBUIHQgACYoQ6AEwBXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=mam%20archaic&f=false)

[image]

[image]

---

Therefore as far as I am concerned, in Western US you don't call your mom, *ma'am. While it does mean *any woman*, you would get a spanking if you called your mom *woman*, wouldn't you? Even the textbook dictionary from OED says mam is a shorthand of ma'am in the US. However in other regions it has been used to mean mother or a mother like figure. 
In summary:

---

- In Northern England or some parts of the UK, it is fine to call your mum, mam or mammy. Even if it has archaic origin to the 16th century for an imitation of a baby's first word (mama), it's not uncommon for a few dialects to speak it in this sense today.
- Mam to mean mother (mammy) though in the US, particularly the South, is to be cautioned as it historically has been derogatory referring to a black woman nursing a white family's children. So even if you're saying ma'am, they won't be able to tell the difference if you're calling them a mam!
- You're more in lucky in Western US, where mam to mean mammy and not ma'am, is unheard of because they too won't be able to tell the difference!

Comment: It's common enough to hear, "Yes, ma'am." in response to a command from an authority figure -- including one's mother. The confusing (I think) comes from associating ma'am *specifically* with a mother.

Comment: @jpaugh You can the say the same for dad — “Yes sir”. But when children use it this way in response to an authority figure, it is usually in an endearing, sarcastic sense. It is not *specific to mom* though.

Comment: Yes, it's not necessarily specific to mothers; but I do think it may be a source of confusion for the OP.

Comment: The quotation about dialects omits to mention that _Mam_ is the word for _mother_ in the Welsh language, so it is used in Wales as well as northern England. It is said that people who are going to meet the Queen are directed to address her as Ma'am to rhyme with jam (i.e. not 'marm'), so it's not just in America that the two words are indistinguishable.

Comment: I'm Australian, but in watching a lot of American TV and movies over the years I've heard children say "yes ma'am" and "yes sir" to their mother or father numerous times. The context was almost always a serious scene where the parent was disciplining the child and the child was clearly trying to meet the parent's demand for respect when replying, and in other, friendlier situations the same child called the parent "mom" or "dad".

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, ma'am does not mean mother. Ma'am is the abbreviated version of madam, which is used to politely or respectfully address a woman.

However, in American English, Madam is used in a more disrespectful way `(term is usually used to address someone running a brothal)` while the Native Bristish English speakers still consider Madam more respectful and formal, when compared to Ma’am.